# Socket.io with Three.js Sphere (OrbitControls)

Tags: javascript, ipad, socket.io, three.js

I'm working on something right now and I can't make it work. I have a [three.js](https://threejs.org/) sphere ("*HTML1*" on Desktop) with controls(`THREE.OrbitControls`).

Which is working good on both computer and tablet. What I want to do is to control that sphere through my iPad, so I loaded a blank scene on an HTML file ("*HTML2*") running on my iPad. That blank *three.js* sphere also has the control function, which I want to send to the server ([socket.io](https://socket.io/)) which is supposed to send them to the Desktop Sphere ("*HTML1*").

My server: The server is getting from the Tablet, but not sending (or the Desktop not receiving)

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('cameraControls', function(controls){
        socket.emit('sendControls', function(controls) {
        console.log('Controls');
        });
    });
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

What the ipad ("*HTML2*") sends (loaded in function render):

```
socket.emit('cameraControls', function(controls){});
```

What the Desktop Sphere receives (also loaded in function render):

```
socket.on('sendControls', function(controls){
         //this.controls = controls;
         console.log("got EVENT");
});
```

Any ideas? It's my first time working with `socket.io`. There are no errors in the Terminal or the Console Log, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an object when emitting an event:

```
socket.emit('cameraControls', {controls: controls});
```

To pass the control information to the desktop, your server code should be:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('cameraControls', function(data){
        socket.emit('sendControls', {controls: data.controls});
    });
    console.log('a user connected');
});
```

then in your desktop's event listener you can access the controls like this:

```
socket.on('sendControls', function(data){
    // this.controls = data.controls
    console.log("got EVENT");
});
```